# Seeded RNG in Distributions.jl

Tags: random, julia, distribution, random-seed

I have a module with functions where I need to ensure that all functions use the same random values. I currently have two solutions, resetting the seed at each call:

```
using Distributions

function random_values(n)
    Random.seed!(1)
    rand(Normal(), n)
end
```

or similarly, instantiating it directly:

```
using Distributions
    
function random_values(n)
    rand(MersenneTwister(1), Normal(), n)
end
```

This works but I have several functions and the code becomes a bit verbose. I would rather set a seed at the module level so that all functions use the same. How can I best achieve this?

Comment: Typically, you'd have methods to take the RNG object as the first argument, and defaults to `Random.GLOBAL_RNG`. Is that still "too verbose"?

Comment: You mean something like this?

`
using Distributions, Random
rng = MersenneTwister(1)

function random_values(rng, n)
    rand(rng, Normal(), n)
end

function random_values_also(rng, n)
    rand(rng, Normal(), n)
end
`

It still wouldn't get me what I need as I would get different numbers from calling the two functions, while I need them to be the same

Comment: Ah, so you want to use the same state every time?

Comment: yes exactly, hence why reseeding at each function call

Comment: OK, that's a somewhat unusual use case. It would work more easily with immutable RNGs, which unfortunately aren't really a thing in Julia. You could use a [counting-based RNG](https://juliarandom.github.io/RandomNumbers.jl/stable/man/random123/) and globally share the counter, but that's not really less verbose. Chad Scherrer has some Markov chain implementations which kind of work this way, I think (reproducing the same values consistently), maybe there something useful to find in his work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is to have two or more functions (f1, f2, ...) that each call rand(). You want them in "sync" so that with a series of function calls each function gets the same series of values for each sequential call of each function (so that the third call to f2 uses the same rand() value as the third call to f1).

For this, you are best off explicitly passing a duplicated RNG object to each of your functions after initializing each to the same seed:

```
init = 1234
rngvector(n) = [MersenneTwister(init) for _ in 1:n]
RNG = rngvector(3)

function f1(rng, ...)
    x = rand(rng, ...)
    ...
end

function f2(rng, ...)
    x = rand(rng, ...)
    ...
end

f1(RNG[1], ...)
```

will then be in sync with

```
f2(RNG[2], ...).
```

This does mean more coding since you add one more argument to each function, but the flexibility and reproducibility that initial extra coding gives you with your Monte Carlo methods when coding the rest of what you do may make it very worthwhile.